# record pcmaudiodata per 10 milisecond without playback

Tags: ios, swift4, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, audiounit

İ need to record pcmaudio per 10 milisecond without playback in swift.

I have tried this code but i can't find how can i stop playback while recording.

[RecordAudio Github Repo](https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/ba815fc23b5d642705f2b1dedfaf0107)

and second question: How can i get PCM data from circular buffer for encode-decode process properly. When I convert recorded audio data to signed byte or unsigned byte or anything else the converted data sometimes will corrupt.  What is the best practice for this kind of process

Answer (score 0):

In the RecordAudio sample code, the audio format is specified as Float (32-bit floats).  When doing a float to integer conversion, you have to make sure your scale and offset results in a value in legal range for the destination type.  e.g. check that -1.0 to 1.0 results in 0 to 256 (unsigned byte), and out-of-range values are clipped to legal values.  Also pay attention to the number of samples you convert, as an Audio Unit callback can vary the frameCount sent (number of samples returned).  You most likely won't get exactly 10 mS in any single RemoteIO callback, but may have to observe a circular buffer filled by multiple callbacks, or a larger buffer that you will have to split.

When RemoteIO is running in play-and-record mode, you can usually silence playback by zeroing the bufferList buffers (after copying, analyzing, or otherwise using the data in the buffers) before returning from the Audio Unit callback.